# WebCam Capture Performance in Java

Tags: java, webcam

I had implemented these solution for webcam capture in java (Sarxos API, JavaCv, Lti-Civil, OpenIMAJ, JMF)  and tested on various processors i3 ( 4 GB RAM), i5 (4 GB RAM) , Core 2 Duo and Atom with different webcams.

I had noticed that in every system `FPS as well as Refresh rate` gets changed

I had been trying with `Logitech C920 webcam` as external cam.

I don't get why these changes happens. When I test Webcam with Logitech WebCam software It's performance of webcam preview remains constant in all systems even with high resolutions. On low resolution above mentioned Java API works well but when i try with high resolution such as 1920x1080 or 1600x1200 webcam preview comes with huge amount of lagging in low processors such as core 2 duo and atom processors.

Please provide your suggestion on this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked default FPS and refresh rate of each 3rd party library that you have used. Values may be differ from one library to other

Comment: What do you mean by default FPS and refresh rate with every resolution fps and refresh rate get changed

Comment: What is your test environment, for example what OS do you use? Thanks!